# Printing The Days of The Week In Java

Tags: java, loops, printing

I'm trying to print this:

```
Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thur  Fri  Sat
  4    3    8    5     4    4    8
```

With a user's input of the hours that they worked each day on the same line so then the total hours worked can be calculated, but I'm not even sure if that's possible. Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
System.out.println("\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t" + "Sun" + "\t" + "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thur" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\t" + "Sat");
        for (int j = 0; j < hoursWorkedPerDay.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter hours worked for Employee " + (j+1) + ":"+ "\t" + " " + " ");

            for (int k = 0; k < hoursWorkedPerDay[0].length; k++) {
                hoursWorkedPerDay[j][k] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        } // End of for loop
```

And my current output:

```
Enter the number of Employee: 2
Enter the name of the employee 1: jeff
Enter the name of the employee 2: lita
                                    Sun Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri Sat
Enter hours worked for Employee 1:    4
6
7
5
8
7
9
Enter hours worked for Employee 2:    3
4
......
```

My question is, is this possible or would I have to just print each vertically? Thanks!

Comment: First get the hours worked, then print the table. Currently, your table is interrupted by the input.

Comment: A side note, you should look into this to save yourself from all those tabs and stuff: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Yeah, it's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the week days before get the value. Like this:

```
//Code before
String[] weekDays = {"Sun","Mon","Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"};
    for (int k = 0; k < hoursWorkedPerDay[0].length; k++) {
        System.out.print(weekDays[k] + ": ");
        hoursWorkedPerDay[j][k] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(); //New line
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it is 'how do I print an array of numbers on a single line'? If so, there are two main ways:

1. Use `print` for each number (with a tab character between) and then `println` to end the line.
2. Join all the numbers into a single string and then use `println` to output the whole string.

Here's a simple Java 8 idiom for printing all the hours in a single statement by joining them into a string with tab delimiters:

```
IntStream.range(0, employeeCount)
    .mapToObj(emp -> Arrays.stream(hoursWorked[emp]).collect(Collectors.joining("\t")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```